# Joomla css path incorrect

Tags: css, joomla, path

i have a problem with the joomla css path...

Go to the url for check : http://www.vendreweb.fr/cx/

You can see the page is correct, but now click on Shipment button... you will see my problem...

The Fields css won't run correctly...

Can you help me please :(

Below the source code of my head index.php template page...

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php echo $this->_charset; ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/avendor-<?php echo $color_scheme; ?>.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/joomla.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/options.css.php?c1=<?php echo str_replace('#','', $c1) ; ?>&amp;c2=<?php echo str_replace('#','', $c2) ; ?>&amp;c3=<?php echo str_replace('#','', $c3) ; ?>&amp;c4=<?php echo str_replace('#','', $c4) ; ?>&amp;bg=<?php echo $bgimage; ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/avendor-font-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/animate.css">

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script> <!--Choix google map-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--Choix google map-->
<script src="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/js/geo.js"></script> <!--Choix google map-->
<style type="text/css">
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {<?php if ( $headline_font == 'headline_googlefont') { echo $headline_googlecss ; } else { echo 'font-family:'.$headline_font.' !important;'; } ?>}
    body, p, .QAmt, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {<?php if($body_font == 'body_googlefont'): echo $body_googlecss; elseif($body_font == 'headline_googlefont'): echo $headline_googlecss; else: echo 'font-family:'.$body_font.' !important;'; endif; ?> }
    <?php if ( $addcss != '' ) echo $addcss ;?>
</style>

<?php if ( $headline_font == 'headline_googlefont' ) echo $headline_googlecode."\n" ;?>
<?php if ( $body_font == 'body_googlefont' ) echo $body_googlecode."\n" ;?>
<script src="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/overrider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tpath; ?>/css/custom.css">
```

</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have added a CSS file called `basestyle.css`.  Here's what it is in the `Shipment` page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.vendreweb.fr/cx/components/com_adsmanager/css/basestyle.css" type="text/css">
```

That CSS file is overriding the styling from the class `form-control` so if you remove the stylesheet from above then it will fix the styling of the page